# Get Python type of Django's model field?

Tags: python, django, django-models

How can I get corresponding Python type of a Django model's field class ?

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    value = models.DecimalField()

type(MyModel._meta.get_field('value'))  # <class 'django.db.models.fields.DecimalField'>
```

I'm looking how can I get corresponding python type for field's value - `decimal.Decimal` in this case.

Any idea ?

p.s. I've attempted to work around this with field's `default` attribute, but it probably won't work in all cases where field has no default value defined.

Comment: do you need to work on the class? Because if you work on an instance, the type of each field would be python's `m=MyModel()` `type(m.value)`

Comment: @Pynchia Yes, I'd need to work on the class. I'm generating dictionary of `field_name: value_type` for serialization purposes, quite unrelated of concrete model instances.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can decide the actual python type programmatically there. Part of this is due to python's dynamic type. If you look at the doc for [converting values to python objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/custom-model-fields/#converting-values-to-python-objects), there is no hard *predefined* type for a field: you can write a custom field that returns object in different types depending on the database value. The doc of [model fields](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/) specifies what Python type corresponds to each field type, so you can do this "statically".

But why would you need to know the Python types in advance in order to serialize them? The serialize modules are supposed to do this for you, just throw them the objects you need to serialize. Python is a dynamically typed language.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. You are probably right. I did take a peek into `DecimalField` sources and it seems only at instance methods like `to_python` field value type is handled. I need this because custom session de/serialization, where either foreignkey fields and other `JSONSerializer` unsupported types like decimalfield exist. Is there some more canonical way how to serialize such types unless recourse to insecure `pickle` ? [Session serializationin Django 1.6+](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/sessions/#session-serialization)

Comment: In custom serializer, `Decimal` is converted to string (not float, because precision may be lost) and for a deserialization, I need to know the type to which the value has to be converted.

Comment: @joanbm In most cases you serialize some Python objects into data, and then deserialize these data back into objects. So they are *trusted* data. Unless you need to deserialize **untrusted** data, it's ok to use pickle.

Comment: @joanbm If a custom de/seralizer is desirable, could you check the type in serializer. You won't get any hints others than the value during deserialization, I can't see why having dict of a field_name: value pairs would help.

Comment: The de/serialization works on data from session and they may contain values from external source, so they are *untrusted*. Although forging session values would require knowledge of SECRET_KEY, it is recommended and set as default in Django 1.6 and newer, to avoid pickle and use json serializer. See the link from 2nd comment.

Comment: I may probably miss something, but when at serialization `Decimal` value is converted to a string, how deserializer may know the string has to be converted to Decimal, for this specific field ? I use field_name → value_type pairs for this.

Comment: @joanbm IMO, You either leave some "hints" in the string, (like decimal: 23.3), or you need to know the data structure you are dealing with when deserializeing (that's why you are building a dict). I would say the former give more flexibility, and it seems pickle works that way.

Answer (score 0):

An ugly alternative is to check the field's repr():

```
if 'DecimalField' in repr(model._meta.get_field(fieldname)):
    return decimal.Decimal
else:
    ...
```

However, you have to this for all types seperatly.